# Can I set up a way where users allowed to create Opportunities only from Contacts?

Tags: opportunity, button, create-records

My initial idea was to hide - New - button from the Opportunities recent list, its already hidden on the Account page layout, but I'm starting to doubt that's the right way, what approach should I use?
Process Builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can totally do that (really depends on your process flow), but you could also show the contact field on the opportunity and make it mandatory (trigger or otherwise). This way you will make contact as a required field, regardless of how the new opportunity is being created.